# Limit Inlines based on Elements in DB (Django>1.7)

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have the following Models (kept simple):

```
models.py:

class Athlete(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class Judge(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield()
```

Now i want each judge to score on an athlete:

```
class Score(models.Model):
  athlete = models.ForeignKey(Athlete)
  judge = models.ForeignKey(Judge)
  score = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

My admin.py so far:

```
class ScoreInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline): 
  model = Score
  fields = ('judge', 'score', )

class AthleteAdmin(ModelAdmin):
  fields = ('name')
  inlines = (ScoreInlineAdmin, )

admin.site.register(Athlete, AthleteAdmin)
```

The Scores should be editable in the Django-Admin-Backend. Here's my problem.
How do I get ScoreInlines for each 'judge' in my db? I don't like to have ChoiceFields and don't need to add more judges from the Inlines.

In other words: how do I get unique 'Inlines'? Is there any way to limit it on a queryset?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together) option to ensure that each judge scores an athlete once at most:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    athlete = models.ForeignKey(Athlete)
    judge = models.ForeignKey(Judge)
    score = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('athlete', 'judge'),
        )
```

However this doesn't help the user interface part of your problem, which is to create an inline for each judge in the Django admin.

Comment: good point though. this saves from having duplicates from the database side.